# Add a unique ID to a menu item list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a different image to show up when the page that is clicked on or that "active" can be dynamic, using javascript/jQuery. I would like to put a unique ID for each li and use javascript.

I'm very new to javascript and don't really know where to start. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
<ul data-identifier="50dd2c0b-3904-4100-9076-627145a3a949" class="active nav-edit " id="nav-main-menu">
     <li class=" nav-link  active ">
         <a href="/about" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link  active ">ABOUT </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="/teachers" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">FOR TEACHERS </a>
     </li>
      <li><a href="/students" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">FOR STUDENTS </a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="/parents" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">FOR PARENTS </a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="/contact" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">CONTACT US </a></li>
     <li><a href="/register" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">REGISTER </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery: You can use `.each` and the incrementing index in the callback function:

```
$("#nav-main-menu li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("id", "id" + index);
});
```

Each `li` will now have an ID starting at `id0` to however long the list is.

Comment: This looks dangerous in that it may generate non-unique ids if applied in multiple places.

Comment: Change the initial identifier for ID then, as it stands, this code can only be used for this list, since it targets the ID.

Comment: I think it would be dangerous just if something is already wrong, which is giving the 'nav-main-menu' id to multiple elements. Otherwise, it would work just fine.

Comment: This worked once I put in:
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#nav-main-menu li").each(function(index) {
     $(this).attr("id", "id" + index);    
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you don't want a numeric ID:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(' ','_'));
})
```

Asuming each `li` element has a link with a different text description, this will assign each `li` element with an id equal to the text value in lowercases and with spaces replaced by underscores.

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/amadac/2/edit)